# Image processing on Android - what libraries can I use?

Tags: android, image-processing, image-manipulation

I need it specifically for image distortion (filters, blurring, etc also welcomed ;) ). Do you know some libraries with appropriate license (Apache, MIT, LGPL also), that I can use? Propriety libraries with reasonable prices - open to them also. Can be in C also.

thanks in advance,
danail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to check out [OpenCV](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) which is developed by Intel. It seems to be very mature and well-documented. Of course, it is also open-source.

Comment: Hi, 10x for the answer. I take a look at it, but I can't find anything about image distortion - do you know where to look and if it supports it?

Comment: You can click on each function name to see an example. I don't know which types of distortions you need specifically, but here's blur: http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/opencv_blur.html, interpolation: http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/opencv_interpolation.html, and threshold: http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/opencv_threshold.html